# Insert into table variable fails with select

Tags: t-sql

I get a syntax error saying this select is malformed...not sure why.

```
Insert into @MyTableVariable (select @new_identity, Name from Company where soemField = 'some text value')
```

@new_identity is just an int var set to scope_identity() after a previous insert statement

Answer (score 2):

```
Insert into @MyTableVariable (newIdentityColName, nameName)
   select @new_identity, Name from Company where someField = 'some text value'
```

Comment: I shouldn't have to specify with that kind of syntax...specifying the fields to be inserted before the values.  Usually it's a shortcut, you just select the fields no need for (newIdentityColName, nameName)

Comment: Did you spell `soemField` correctly? I guess you don't have to. It's just good practice if there are columns add, removed, or rearranged.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict: see [Aaron Bertrand's "Bad Habits to Kick" blog post on the topic](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)

Comment: no, I can put this in and it returns valid data from the select: select 1, Name from Company where soemField = 'some text value'.  Yes the identity has a valid value.

Comment: Remove your parentheses around your SELECT statement.  The answer was showing you that parens following the table name are interpreted as a column list.  It's not required, but it's a good habit to be explicit about the columns you intend to insert.